# How to filter an array by deleting a tag?

Tags: javascript, arrays, filter, tags

i'm trying to refilter an array but the path to access the choosen parameter seems to be a bit tricky.
The full project is supposed to filter on 3 parameters but the other 2 are working.

On click on filter, we're filtering correctly. But on click on the span, i'm suppose to start to filter again for each tag currently displayed.

How to make it works (here if we cancel the filter we're supposed to get both recipes), but how to make it works if more recipes and more tags are applied ?

```
    <button class="btn">Filter</button>
    <span class="tag">Jus de citron</span>
```

```
async function getRecipes() {
    const response = await ((await fetch("./data.json")).json())
    const recipes = response.recipes;
    console.log(recipes)
    return ({ recipes: [...recipes] });
};


async function filter() {
    const { recipes } = await getRecipes()
    const btn = document.querySelector(".btn");
    let filteredRecipes = [];
    btn.addEventListener("click", () => { //Only click once (no security for example)
        filteredRecipes.push(recipes.filter(recipe => {
            recipe.ingredients.filter(({ingredient}) => {
                if(ingredient.includes("Jus de citron")) return filteredRecipes.push(recipe)
            })
        }))
        filteredRecipes = filteredRecipes.slice(0, filteredRecipes.length-1)
        console.log(filteredRecipes)
    })
}

function deleteTag() {
    const tags = document.querySelectorAll(".tag");

    tags.forEach(tag => {
        tag.addEventListener("click", () => {
            if(tag.classList.contains("tag")) {
                //Filter
            }
            console.log(filteredRecipes)
            //Expected output (2 recipes)
        })

    }) 
}


filter()
deleteTag()
```

the datas :

```
{"recipes": [
    {
        "id": 1,
        "name" : "Limonade de Coco",
        "servings" : 1,
        "ingredients": [
            {
                "ingredient" : "Lait de coco",
                "quantity" : 400,
                "unit" : "ml"
            },
            {
                "ingredient" : "Jus de citron",
                "quantity" : 2
            },
            {
                "ingredient" : "Crème de coco",
                "quantity" : 2,
                "unit" : "cuillères à soupe"
            },
            {
                "ingredient" : "Sucre",
                "quantity" : 30,
                "unit" : "grammes"
            },
            {
                "ingredient": "Glaçons"
            }
        ],
        "time": 10,
        "description": "Mettre les glaçons à votre goût dans le blender, ajouter le lait, la crème de coco, le jus de 2 citrons et le sucre. Mixer jusqu'à avoir la consistence désirée",
        "appliance": "Blender",
        "ustensils": ["cuillère à Soupe", "verres", "presse citron" ]
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "name" : "Poisson Cru à la tahitienne",
        "servings": 2,
        "ingredients": [
            {
                "ingredient" : "Thon Rouge (ou blanc)",
                "quantity" : 200,
                "unit" : "grammes"
            },
            {
                "ingredient" : "Concombre",
                "quantity" : 1
            },
            {
                "ingredient" : "Tomate",
                "quantity" : 2
            },
            {
                "ingredient" : "Carotte",
                "quantity" : 1
            },
            {
                "ingredient" : "Citron Vert",
                "quantity" : 5
            },
            {
                "ingredient" : "Lait de coco",
                "quantity" : 100,
                "unit" : "ml"
            }
        ],
        "time": 60,
        "description": "Découper le thon en dés, mettre dans un plat et recouvrir de jus de citron vert (mieux vaut prendre un plat large et peu profond). Laisser reposer au réfrigérateur au moins 2 heures. (Si possible faites-le le soir pour le lendemain. Après avoir laissé mariner le poisson, coupez le concombre en fines rondelles sans la peau et les tomates en prenant soin de retirer les pépins. Rayer la carotte. Ajouter les légumes au poissons avec le citron cette fois ci dans un Saladier. Ajouter le lait de coco. Pour ajouter un peu plus de saveur vous pouver ajouter 1 à 2 cuillères à soupe de Crème de coco",
        "appliance": "Saladier",
        "ustensils": ["presse citron"]
    }
]}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```js
let filteredRecipes = recipes.filter(
    recipe => recipe.ingredients.some(
        ({ingredient}) => ingredient.includes("Jus de citron")
    )
);
```

You do not need to `push` items into `filteredRecipes`. The arrow function passed to `Array.filter()` only requires that you return a `true` or `false` value to indicate if the element should be included. `Array.some()` will return `true` if the arrow function passed to it returns `true` for at least one of the array elements.

Comment: Thanks, it's working even on the main project. I never think about the some method.